# Enumerating records by date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say we have 5 records for items sold on particular dates like this

```
Date of Purchase             Qty
2016-11-29 19:33:50.000       5
2017-01-03 20:09:49.000       4
2017-02-23 16:21:21.000       11
2016-11-29 14:33:51.000       2
2016-12-02 16:24:29.000       4
```

I´d like to enumerate each record by the date in order with an extra column like this:

```
Date of Purchase             Qty      Order
2016-11-29 19:33:50.000       5         1
2017-01-03 20:09:49.000       4         3
2017-02-23 16:21:21.000       11        4
2016-11-29 14:33:51.000       2         1
2016-12-02 16:24:29.000       4         2
```

Notice how both dates on 2016-11-29 have the same order number because I only want to order the records by the date and not by the datetime. How would I create this extra column in just plain SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dense_rank()` and ordering by the `date` of `DateOfPurchase`

```
select * 
  , [Order] = dense_rank() over (order by convert(date,DateOfPurchase))
from t
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FAAQL92440

returns:

```
+---------------------+-----+-------+
|   DateOfPurchase    | Qty | Order |
+---------------------+-----+-------+
| 2016-11-29 19:33:50 |   5 |     1 |
| 2016-11-29 14:33:51 |   2 |     1 |
| 2016-12-02 16:24:29 |   4 |     2 |
| 2017-01-03 20:09:49 |   4 |     3 |
| 2017-02-23 16:21:21 |  11 |     4 |
+---------------------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: such a smart solution. Thank you very much